# On a problem from the Middle European Mathematical olympiad (2010) in pablo soberon book

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

I doing some combinatorial exercises to Gai practice when I stumbled on  a problem from the Middle European Mathematical Olympiad (2010) in Pablo Soberon's book.

(Middle European Mathematical Olympiad 2010) All positive divisors of a positive integer N are written on a blackboard. Two players A and B play
the following game, taking alternate moves. In the first move, the player A erases N.
If the last erased number is d, then the next player erases either a divisor of d or a
multiple of d. The player who cannot make a move loses. Determine all numbers N
for which A has a winning strategy.
and here's the proposed solution

Let $N = p^{a_1}_
1 p^{a_2}_
2 ···p^{a_k}_
k$ be the prime factorization of N. In an arbitrary move the player writes down a divisor of N, which we can represent as
a sequence $(b_1,b_2,..., b_k)$, where $b_i \leq a_i$. Thus, a sequence $(b_1,b_2,...,b_k)$ can
be followed by $(c_1,c_2,...,c_k)$ if either $0 ≤ c_i ≤ b_i$ for all i, or $b_i ≤ c_i ≤ a_i$
for all i. If at least one of the $a_i$ is odd, then B has a winning strategy. Suppose that $a_1$ is odd. Split the sequences into pairs of the form $(b_1,b_2,...,b_k)$,
and $(a_1 − b_1,b_2,b_3,...,b_k)$. After A plays any sequence, B plays the other in
the pair. This is a winning strategy for B. If all $a_i$ are even, we can use a similar argument to split the sequences different from $(a_1,a_2,...,a_k)$ into pairs. If
$(b_1,b_2,...,b_k) = (a_1,a_2,...,a_k)$, let j be the smallest index such that $b_j < a_j$ .
Then the pair of $(b_1,b_2,...,b_k)$ is $(b_1,b_2,...,b_{j−1},a_j − b_{j − 1},b_{j+1},...,b_k)$
(note that $b_j = a_j − b_j − 1$ since $a_j$ is even). In the first turn A plays the sequence
$(a_1,a_2,...,a_k)$. After a move from B, A only needs to respond with the pair of the
last sequence played. Thus the numbers for which A has a winning strategy are the
perfect squares.

I honestly didn't understand why they imposed the condition that $b_i<a_i$ and what the $(c_1,c_2,...,c_n)$ sequence has to do with the problem along with conditions followed by it

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange, writing in [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) improves readability and makes it easier for others to answer your questions.

Comment: If you write p_1^{a_1} but put a dollar sign at the beginning and another at the end you get $p_1^{a_1}$ which is much easier to read than your pa1 1.

Comment: If you want someone to answer your question, zeemaths, I strongly suggest you take the advice to make the question more readable.

Comment: I help to edit now, please follow the above comment to ask question next time..